# How to find if file is in file system cache in Windows?

Tags: windows, operating-system, filesystems

I guess `NTFS` (file system of `Windows`) has some cache. Suppose I have a file, which is frequently accessed (read-only). How can I check if this file is in the file system cache ? Can I increase the file system cache size ?

Comment: Never tried it myself, but part of your question is answered [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/07/08/increase-the-filesystem-memory-cache-size-in-windows-7/).

Comment: Uh, no. This article refers to caching of non-file-data data structures and not file data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way from user space to detect if a file has been cached (partially or completely). In a multithreaded/multiprocessing environment, once you have received this information, it is instantly out of date.

There is no "limit" to caching in Windows that can be adjusted (although my data is Windows 7 and prior versions). The cache manager simply uses the memory manager to place data into memory and get callbacks when physical memory needs to be reclaimed (say, by an application's demands). The memory manager trades off file cache against memory demands of processes.

Answer (score 4):

Check

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/13/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap.aspx

You can use [RamMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) which will give you a dedicated view of how current system is caching files.

Also to mention, cache isn't based on file, more by block/page.